# Angular Validation Error as 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. (

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Here i wrote a small Validation Property for EName Validation when i try 2 Load Html page i'm getting Error as 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. (

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core"
import { Employee } from "../../../templates/employee/employee"
import { Validators, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms"
@Component({
    selector: "customer-ui",
    templateUrl: "../../../templates/customer/customer.html"
})
export class JamComponent implements OnInit {
    EmpleoyeeForm: FormGroup;
    public constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.EmpleoyeeForm = this.fb.group({
            EmpName: ['', [Validators.required]]

        })
    }
```

**Htmlcode**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" novalidate [formGroup]="EmpleoyeeForm">

    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (EmpleoyeeForm.get('EmpName').touched ||
                                                  EmpleoyeeForm.get('EmpName').dirty) &&
                                                    !EmpleoyeeForm.get('EmpName').valid }">

            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="EmpName" [(ngModel)]="EmpName" />

        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you import `FormsModule` in @ngModule `imports` list ?

Comment: Yes i impororted formsmodule

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31981

Answer (score 12):

If you already have the CommonModule/BrowserModule and it's still not working, also make sure you typed the attribute correctly. I had `ngclass` instead of `ngClass` (notice the 'C').

Comment: ya, in my case I was relying on intellij code completion `ngc[tab]` and it didn't fix the casing (which I assumed it would)

Comment: I can't believe I found an answer with 10 votes on SO about a typo and I'm truely grateful it's there, I would have smashed my head on my desk if I didn't found it...

Answer (score 2):

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

...

imports: [CommonModule],

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the component is imported and added to **declarations** array in **app.module.ts** as shown below:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { JamComponent } from './jam.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    JamComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```