# Angular fontawsome sizing - Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon'

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I'm looking for a way to sizing my component
using fontawesome library like

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import {
  faBell
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(
  faBell
);


@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'iwdf-icon-bell',
  template: `<fa-icon [ngClass]="cls" [icon]="['fas', 'bell']"></fa-icon>`,
  styles: [`:host {
    display: inline-block;
  }`]
})
export class IconBellComponent{
  @Input() cls: string;
}
```

but I've got this error:

```
Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'fa-icon'.
```

I know I could cheat like:

@Component({

```
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'iwdf-icon-bell',
  template: `<fa-icon class="{{cls}}" [icon]="['fas', 'bell']"></fa-icon>`,
  styles: [`:host {
    display: inline-block;
  }`]
})
export class IconBellComponent{
  @Input() cls: string;
}
```

but I'm wondering if there is any other way.

Any idea ?

### UPDATE

I worked it out with:

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'icon-angledown',
  template: `<fa-icon [className]="cls" [icon]="['fas', 'angle-down']"></fa-icon>`,
  styles: [`:host {
    display: inline-block;
  }`]
})
export class IconAngleDownComponent{
  @Input() cls: string = '';
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870542/angular2-validation-error-as-ngclass-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div

Comment: If the component under the root module make sure that BrowserModule is imported. If it is in a child module import CommonModule. These imports being missing will give you that error when trying to use common directives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Validation Error as 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. (](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870542/angular2-validation-error-as-ngclass-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding BrowserModule in NgModule "imports"

`@NgModule(
  imports: [BrowserModule]
)`

OR

use expression in ngClass directly

Answer (score 0):

```
<i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'cls','fas-bell'}"></i>
```

Try moving the fa-icon class itself in ngClass